# Can htaccess "try" different extensions?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a folder with images uploaded by users in a few different formats. The files get numbered by my upload script with a unique ID.

When displaying them via php, I want to be able to link to them without knowing (or having to save in the database) their extension (i.e. `images/42`, `images/69` and not `images/42.png`, `images/69.jpeg`. I have been doing some research but can't really come up with a way to write my `.htaccess` correctly. What I've done so far doesn't work and I had no success either trying to come up with my rewrite conditions. Any suggestions?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$    $1.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)    [QSA,L]
```

I've found this but can't really adapt to my problem: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can manually try each extension in turn. Each extension will require a different rule. The first extension that matches will "win". If an extension matches then force the respective mime-type.

I assume your image URLs are of the form `/images/<number>`. This needs to be specific otherwise we will unnecessarily test the wrong URLs.

For example, near the top of your root `.htaccess` file:

```
# Check for ".webp" file (and check browser support)
# NB: If webp not supported then there needs to be a fallback (.png or .jpg)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} (?:^|,)image/webp(?:,|$)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0.webp -f
RewriteRule ^images/\d+$ $0.webp [T=image/webp,L]

# Check for ".png" file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0.png -f
RewriteRule ^images/\d+$ $0.png [T=image/png,L]

# Check for ".jpg" file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0.jpg -f
RewriteRule ^images/\d+$ $0.jpg [T=image/jpeg,L]

# Check for ".jpeg" file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0.jpeg -f
RewriteRule ^images/\d+$ $0.jpeg [T=image/jpeg,L]

# Check for ".gif" file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0.gif -f
RewriteRule ^images/\d+$ $0.gif [T=image/gif,L]
```

The `$0` backreference contains the entire URL-path that is matched, eg. `image/42`. Each `RewriteCond` directive checks for the existence of the file with the respective file extension before internally rewriting the request to that file. The `T` flag ensures the correct `Content-Type` header is sent with the response.

---

> images uploaded by users in a few different formats.

An alternative approach is to convert the image into a specific format as part of the upload process. So you *always* rewrite to `.png` (for example) - which will be more performant. And this has the added "security" benefit that *malicious* files (scripts that are "pretending" to be images) will get rejected since the image conversion will likely fail.

---

#### MultiViews (alternative)

Alternatively, you could simply enable MultiViews and let mod_negotiation do the work. mod_negotiation then checks various file extensions that return the appropriate mime-type and will return a resource that matches.

For example:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

No mod_rewrite directives are necessary.

HOWEVER, you don't have as much control over this, unless you manually create a type map in the server config and this might conflict and cause problems if you have other mod_rewrite directives. MultiViews will apply to everything unless you restrict it to certain paths.

---

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$    $1.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)    [QSA,L]
> ```

You can't do it in a single rule like this. This directive also matches *everything* (ie. `^(.*)/?$`) - which naturally includes every URL that does not map to an image. The *substitution* string is an ordinary string, not a regex, so a construct like `(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)` is seen as literal text. The `QSA` flag is irrelevant here. The query string is appended by default anyway, but do you image URLs have a query string to begin with?